# How do I easily manipulate a timestamp key in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, time

I just started using Python as hobby, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I recently installed a power meter on my computer, and I'm using it to track its power consumption. It gives me real-time minute readings exported to a csv file.

I have parsed and read the file, and now I have a dictionary where the key is a timestamp, stored as a struct_time from the time library. Currently, the dictionary has readings which were taken every minute. I'd like to create a new dictionary whose keys are hour timestamps, and whose values are the sum of the individual minute readings.

I thought about looping through the dictionary with a counter mod 60, but I'm told that isn't very Pythonic. Also, there's no guarantee that there exists 60 readings for every hour. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd suggest using the [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) class instead of `time.time_struct`, since the latter is really just a weak wrapper around a 9-tuple but the former is a fully-featured class with operator overloads etc.  Next, you can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to easily construct your desired total readings:

```
# power_reading is the data type corresponding to one set of power readings
# (it could be a simple float, or a tuple, or a class if you want; just make
# sure that you can add them together)
hourly_readings = collections.defaultdict(power_reading)
minutely_readings = { ... };  # dict of time.struct_time ==> power_reading

for timestamp, reading in minutely_readings.iteritems():
    hour = datetime.datetime(timestamp.tm_year, timestamp.tm_mon,
                             timestamp.tm_mday, timestamp.tm_hour);
    hourly_readings[hour] += reading
```

If `power_reading` is a tuple, you can't use `+=` (since that concatenates the tuples instead of doing an element-wise addition), so you'll have to do something like this instead:

```
hourly_readings[hour] = tuple(map(sum, zip(hourly_readings[hour], reading)))
```

Answer (score 9):

If my understanding to your question is right, this should do the job:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in readings.iteritems():
    output[key.tm_hour] += value
```

The advantage of using [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is that it will handle the case of missing hours by returning 0 as a value.

**Edit:**

As Cristian pointed out the OP might have readings for several days. In that case I follow the suggestion first introduced by Adam Rosenfield with a slight modification:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
output = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in readings.iteritems():
    output[datetime(*x[:4])] += value
```

This will construct the date from the day, month, year and hour without minutes or seconds.

Comment: My readings do span multiple days - multiple weeks, in fact. I appreciate your answer though!

Comment: What is the ``x`` in ``datetime(*x[:4])`` referring to?!

Answer (score 0):

One line in Python3:

```
{time.struct_time(i+(0,0,0,0)):sum(k[1] for k in j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(sorted(D.items()),lambda x:x[0][:4])}
```

Python2:

```
result={}
tmp=(0,)*4
for i,j in itertools.groupby(sorted(D.items()),lambda x:x[0][:4]):
    result[time.struct_time(i+tmp)]=sum(k[1] for k in j)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with `python3-3.1.2-14.fc14.x86_64`. I'm getting a dictionary with *... 15:14:00* and *... 15:10:00* as keys.